# How to align Text of row header at DataGrid in WPF?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, header, row

I would like to align Text of row header at DataGrid in WPF.
Below code not work for me.

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" LoadingRow="OnLoadingRow" RowHeaderWidth="106">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5 0"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>

            <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Path=Header}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
```

This code work like this.
[Result of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivi3Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

*That works:*

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" LoadingRow="OnLoadingRow" RowHeaderWidth="106">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Path=Header}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```